# How to compare values in a list created with *map() function?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

**This is my Python code:**

```
class Holiday:
    def __init__(self, month, day, hours):
        self.month = month
        self.day = day
        self.hours = hours

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Month = {self.month}, Day = {self.day}, Hours = {self.hours}'


list_of_holidays = []

with open("Holidays.txt") as afile:
    for line in afile.readlines()[1:]:
        list_of_holidays.append(Holiday(*map(str.strip, line.split("/"))))
```

**This is the output:**

Month = 1, Day = 6, Hours = 10-18

Month = 4, Day = 15, Hours = 10-18

Month = 4, Day = 17, Hours = 10-18

Holidays.txt has the format: month / day / hours

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
day_input = 6

month_input = 1

if month and day in list_of_holidays:

print(Hours)


-> and have Hours be the corresponding Hours on the same row.I simply can't get this to work how I want it and there's definitely something I'm missing in the code
```

I simply can't get this to work how I want it and there's definitely something I'm missing in the code.

Is there a way to do this and compare the inputs directly to the list and getting the corresponding Hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you define each instance of `Holiday` isn't really relevant, so the solution is the same whether or not you used `*map(...)` to provide the arguments to `Holiday`.

You just need to check the given month and day against each holiday.

```
for holiday in list_of_holidays:
    if month_input == holiday.month and day_input == holiday.day:
        print(holiday.hours)
        break  # If you know there won't be more than one such holiday
```